# SpringBoot: Can I @Autowire Bean in runnable JAR from JAR provided using java -cp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, autowired

I have runnable JAR A which contains interface:

```
interface FooInterface {
    void foo();
    ...
}
```

In JAR A I have also class which is trying to autowire FooInterface implmenetation:

```
class Other{
    @Autowired 
    FooInterface fooInterfaceImplementation;
    ...
}
```

In other project B I have jar A as external library and implementation of the FooInterface:

```
@Component
class BarClass implements FooInterface {
    void foo(){...}
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to run my runnable A JAR with classes from JAR B by using command:

```
java -jar A.jar -cp B.jar
```

But it ends with following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ocado.cfc.optimisation.AlgorithmInterface' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:348)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
        at com.ocado.cfc.optimisation.Executable.main(Executable.java:81)
```

Is it possible to autowire required bean in that way?
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible if you try to use `-jar` and `-cp` together. `-cp` is ignored when you use  `-jar`.

If you want to have more than one jar on the classpath you can pass them both in using `-cp`. You'll then have to also provide the name of the main class that you want to launch. Given that you appear to be using Spring Boot, that might look like this:

```
java -cp A.jar:B.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

You may also be interested in Spring Boot's [`PropertiesLauncher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) that allows you to create an executable jar with a configurable class path.

Answer (score 1):

yes, in order to spring to detect/scan the beans from the class path JAR files, you need to add the packages using the class level annotation `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.ocado")` to your spring boot launcher class.